# How to optimize a solution?

Tags: python-3.x, optimization

I am able to write the brute force approach but I am lacking in optimizing my code. Could you tell me how to do that?
For example:
Given an integer array nums and an integer k, return the number of non-empty subarrays that have a sum divisible by k.

Input: nums = [4,5,0,-2,-3,1], k = 5

Output: 7

Explanation:

There are 7 subarrays with a sum divisible by k = 5:

1. [4, 5, 0, -2, -3, 1],
2. [5],
3. [5, 0],
4. [5, 0, -2, -3],
5. [0],
6. [0, -2, -3],
7. [-2, -3]

My sol:

```
class Solution:
    def subarraysDivByK(self, nums: List[int], k: int) -> int:
        l=[]
        for i in range(len(nums)+1):
            for j in range(i):
                l.append(nums[j:i])
        count=0
        for i in l:
            s=sum(i)
            if(s%k==0):
                count+=1
        return count
```

It is getting memory limit exceeded.

Comment: Can you change your question to a [mre]?  When I tried to reproduce your 'memory limit' I did not get an error. It just returned `7`.

Comment: Can you also use a more descriptive question title ? "How to optimize a solution?" is very vague and generic (there is a worse title though: "How to solve a problem").